# How do I resize my li using classes and css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to resize my `<li><a href="Next word needs resizing">WORD HERE NEEDS RESIZING</a></li>`

Here is some code for example

```
<li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a> </li>
<li > <a href="#"> Computer Repairs </a> </li>
<li > <a href="#" > Shop </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> About </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
```

Comment: Are you looking for `font-size`, or ...?

Comment: Yes but only for the words right after the > after the href. How can I change the font size in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the css `font-size`:

```css
li a {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a> </li>
<li > <a href="#"> Computer Repairs </a> </li>
<li > <a href="#" > Shop </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> About </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
```

Or you can add classes:

```css
.resize {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<li> <a href="index.html" class="resize"> Home </a> </li>
<li > <a href="#" class="resize"> Computer Repairs </a> </li>
<li > <a href="#" class="resize"> Shop </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#" class="resize"> About </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#" class="resize"> Contact </a> </li>
```

**NOTE:** 30px is just an example value, use whatever you want.

Comment: @MichaelCallahan No problem! Which method did you end up using?

Comment: Adding classes, I tried using classes before and it started acting up and my css didn't affect it

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like so:

```
li {
    font-size: 16px; // or any other value
}
```

OR

```
li a {
    font-size: 16px; // or any other value
}
```

BTW: If you can't figure this out, I suggest to check out resources online [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
li a{
  font-size:28px;
}
```

```html
<li> <a href="#"> Home </a> </li>
<li > <a href="#"> Computer Repairs </a> </li>
<li > <a href="#" > Shop </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> About </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
```

`font-size` 28 is only for example you can use whatever you want as per you requirement